# Render imgui on top of existing Java framework

Tags: java, editors, imgui

I have never done this before, but we need to build game editor, on top of our existing java game SDK.

We want to use java version of **imgui**. I can easily create imgui window and put UI into it, but how can I also put there our game?

Or run our game and render imgui on top of it?
Basically have scene view like in UI / Unity, but editor and windows on top.

Comment: This is a tough job..